# Adding default text value (suggestion) to kendo datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I am using a kendodatepicker controller as a calendar and I want it to show "Enter Date" when page loads, I try to put it as a value but it doesn't recognize string, aria-label is not what I'm looking for I think... Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbHt5/

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("monthpicker")
          .Value("Enter Date")
          .Min(DateTime.Now))
```

Comment: use placeholder http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: thanks! I thought kendo doesn't offer any support for placeholder, but it works, although not in IE9-

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as placeholder but this gonna work in every browser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#monthpicker").kendoDatePicker({
        start: "year",
        depth: "year",
        format: "MMMM yyyy"
    });

    var enterDateMessage = 'Enter date...';

    $("#monthpicker").val(enterDateMessage);

    $("#monthpicker").focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() === enterDateMessage){
            $("#monthpicker").val('');
        }
    });

    $("#monthpicker").blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() === ''){
            $("#monthpicker").val(enterDateMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbHt5/2/